# How to check existence of a record in a model from current authenticated user in Django template?

Tags: python, django

Code below checks whether a user added a product in cart or not. If it is added to cart by this current user it should show `remove from cart` button else it should show a simple form to add product in cart.

```
{% for ordereditem in item.ordereditems_set.all %}
  {% if ordereditem.quantity > 0 and ordereditem.user.username == user.username %}
    <a href="{{ item.get_remove_from_cart_url }}">Remove from cart</a>
  {% elif not ordereditem %}  # here!
  <!-- else if there is no record of 'ordereditem' from current user show this form to add it to cart-->
    <form class="d-flex justify-content-left" method="POST" action="{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" name="number" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
  </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the problem lies here `{% elif not ordereditem %}` it seems like my current if statement doesn't meet the condition I expect. I tried using `{% else %}` but it still shows the form even after adding product to cart.

This is how models look like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,
                                         decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Discount', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/')
    image_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LABEL_CHOICE)
    associated_items = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)


class OrderedItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderedItems)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the github [link](https://github.com/basirpayenda/ecommerce-website). Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`{% empty %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) here:

```
{% for ordereditem in item.ordereditems_set.all %}
    ...
{% empty %}
    No items
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I added that but it shows `remove from cart button` whether it is added in cart or not, because if you have a close look to `OrderedItem` model there is a foreign key to `User`  model. Chances are that there are always record of `ordereditem` from other users if not from this user.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this logic in the template, you should be doing it in your view, e.g. `users_orders = OrderedItem.objects.filter(user_id=...)`